# How to ask user to enter date in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

How to ask user to enter date and then get the data between the date given by the user and the end date in MYSQL.

> I have declared it using

`DECLARE @x
SET @x = END DATE
DECLARE @Y
SET @Y = ['ENTER DATE']`

I need to write a query which asks user to enter the `Y` date.

Comment: Mysql does not have a way of accepting user input.Nor does any other sql dialect as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  You need to write an interface to do this.  You're interface can be either a command line application or alternatively you can create a web application.  The language / technologies you choose to do this will prompt the user for the date, accept and parse the input and pass this date to the MySQL query.